# Inverse drawing of Bitmap on Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

How can I inverse the image drawed into a Canvas?

I has the following:

```
        canvas.save();
        canvas.drawBitmap(image.current(), null, currentBounds(), Paints.BLANK);
        canvas.restore();
```

How can I make the current image be drawed fliped on x-axis into the currentBounds()?

I already found some answers indicating usage of Matrix, but I wan't to know if there's a easier way? Such a Paint with some flag turned on.

EDIT:

Following is my try with Matrix transformations:

```
    Rect currentBounds = currentBounds();


    currentBounds.offset((int)offset.x(), (int)offset.y());

    float scale = image.current().getWidth() / currentBounds.width();

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setScale(- scale - 1, scale + 1);
    matrix.postTranslate(currentBounds.left, currentBounds.top);

    canvas.drawBitmap(image.current(), matrix, Paints.BLANK);
    canvas.drawRect(currentBounds, Paints.STROKE_BLUE);
```

The following is the result of this draw:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/28683814/game.png

As can be seen, the sprite is being drawed from 0,0 to left and it's not fully completes the currentBounds(), what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7775153/314784) is the best way. It uses matrices, but it isn't that hard.

Comment: using a matrix should be straight forward.

Comment: probably is the best way, please read my edited answer to see the new error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved this way:

```
    Rect currentBounds = currentBounds();
    currentBounds.offset((int)offset.x(), (int)offset.y());

    float scale = (float) currentBounds.width() / (float) image.current().getWidth();

    boolean leftMovement = movingLeft();

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setScale(leftMovement ? -scale : scale, scale);
    matrix.postTranslate(leftMovement ? currentBounds.right : currentBounds.left, currentBounds.top);

    canvas.drawBitmap(image.current(), matrix, Paints.BLANK);
```

But this "leftMovement ? currentBounds.right : currentBounds.left" does not looks right

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
canvas.scale(-1,0,width/2,height/2);
```

as mentioned by my own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9610066/458968).

Although, I would point out that it will take you about a minute to understand Matrices, and it'll make you a better Android programmer.

Comment: Actually, this make my draw disappear I understand matrices, I was just wondering what I would do with the scale applied on the game (bounds are not the original bitmap size), but it's possible to do it trought the matrix too. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. I think this is quite easy.

```
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(180, x, y);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, null);
        canvas.restore();
```

Comment: this rotates, I need to flip the current matrix